# Exporting a mesh of specific dimensions

Tags: modeling, mesh, export

Although I'm new to blender, creating a simple mesh (e.g. cylinder) of specific dimensions is easy.

However, when I export the mesh, open it with meshlab and measure the dimensions, I keep getting the same cylinder with default dimensions.

Is there any step I'm missing (something like "apply") before the export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I found the solution at a unlikely [place](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/183143/blender-problems.html).

> in object mode, select all the meshes (press A), press CONTROL-A (apply menu), then select APPLY ROTATION, then again APPLY TRANSLATION, then APPLY SCALE

After these steps, exporting the mesh and opening it with Meshlab, I can finally see that the mesh file has the proper dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mismatch that is giving you a challenge is between the default sizes of the dimensions. The default size of a unit in Blender is one meter. The default size of a unit of measurement in Meshlab is one centimeter. If you create a blender object that measures 4 blender units in one dimension, and 2 blender units in another, when imported to meshlab, it will be 4 centimeters in one dimension, and two centimeters in the other.

You either need to account for the difference in sizes when you create your model, or change the units in Blender so that one grid square is one centimeter, instead of one meter.

Comment: This is indeed true brasshat. The problem was not this though, as I was setting the new dimensions in metric units. The problem was that the changes were not applied to the exported mesh. The accepted answer (it will be accepted tomorrow, since I'm a new user and I have limited rights) gives the desired solution ;)